# How can I remove a substring from a given String?

Tags: java, string

Is there an easy way to remove substring from a given `String` in Java?

Example: `"Hello World!"`, removing `"o"` → `"Hell Wrld!"`

Answer (score 522, accepted):

You could easily use [`String.replace()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29):

```
String helloWorld = "Hello World!";
String hellWrld = helloWorld.replace("o","");
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use StringBuffer

```
StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer("Hello World");
text.replace( StartIndex ,EndIndex ,String);
```

Answer (score 10):

Check out [Apache StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html):

> - `static String  replace(String text, String searchString, String replacement)` Replaces all occurrences of a String within another
>     String.
> - `static String  replace(String text, String searchString, String replacement, int max)` Replaces a String with another String inside a
>     larger String, for the first max values of the search String.
> - `static String  replaceChars(String str, char searchChar, char replaceChar)` Replaces all occurrences of a character in a String with
>     another.
> - `static String  replaceChars(String str, String searchChars, String replaceChars)` Replaces multiple characters in a String in one go.
> - `static String  replaceEach(String text, String[] searchList, String[] replacementList)` Replaces all occurrences of Strings within
>     another String.
> - `static String  replaceEachRepeatedly(String text, String[] searchList, String[] replacementList)` Replaces all occurrences of
>     Strings within another String.
> - `static String  replaceOnce(String text, String searchString, String replacement)` Replaces a String with another String inside a
>     larger String, once.
> - `static String  replacePattern(String source, String regex, String replacement)` Replaces each substring of the source String that
>     matches the given regular expression with the given replacement using
>     the Pattern.DOTALL option.

Comment: Just benchmarked the replacePattern and it's 6x slower than running custom Java code.

Comment: @AlexArvanitidis Will you please share the **custom Java code**? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

```
replace('regex', 'replacement');
replaceAll('regex', 'replacement');
```

In your example,

```
String hi = "Hello World!"
String no_o = hi.replaceAll("o", "");
```

Answer (score 8):

This works good for me.

```
String hi = "Hello World!"
String no_o = hi.replaceAll("o", "");
```

or you can use

```
String no_o = hi.replace("o", "");
```

Answer (score 6):

You should have to look at `StringBuilder/StringBuffer` which allow you to delete, insert, replace char(s) at specified [offset](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Answer (score 5):

You can use Substring also for replacing with existing string:

```
var str = "abc awwwa";
var Index = str.indexOf('awwwa');
str = str.substring(0, Index);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
```

Above method will help to get the answer.

```
String check = "Hello World";
check = check.replaceAll("o","");
```

Answer (score 4):

If you know the start and end index you may use this

```
string = string.substring(0, start_index) + string.substring(end_index, string.length());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [guava's](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [CharMatcher.removeFrom](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html#removeFrom%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) function.

**Example:**

```
 String s = CharMatcher.is('a').removeFrom("bazaar");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private static void replaceChar() {
    String str = "hello world";
    final String[] res = Arrays.stream(str.split(""))
            .filter(s -> !s.equalsIgnoreCase("o"))
            .toArray(String[]::new);
    System.out.println(String.join("", res));
}
```

In case you have some complicated logic to filter the char, just another way instead of `replace()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the implementation to delete all the substrings from the given string

```
public static String deleteAll(String str, String pattern)
{
    for(int index = isSubstring(str, pattern); index != -1; index = isSubstring(str, pattern))
        str = deleteSubstring(str, pattern, index);

    return str;
}

public static String deleteSubstring(String str, String pattern, int index)
{
    int start_index = index;
    int end_index = start_index + pattern.length() - 1;
    int dest_index = 0;
    char[] result = new char[str.length()];


    for(int i = 0; i< str.length() - 1; i++)
        if(i < start_index || i > end_index)
            result[dest_index++] = str.charAt(i);

    return new String(result, 0, dest_index + 1);
}
```

The implementation of isSubstring() method is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53113110/4773290)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
String helloWorld = "Hello World";
String target = "e";
String replacement = "";
String replacedString = helloWorld.replace(target, replacement);

The answer is = Hllo World
```

or you can use regex

```
String original = "Java is one of best languages. OOP can be used in Java";
String regexTarget = "\\bJava\\b";
String replacedWord = original.replaceAll(regexTarget, "Python");

The answer is = Python is one of best languages. OOP can be used in Python
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @DwB answer, you can also use [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) `remove`:

```
String hello = "hello world";
String hellYeah = StringUtils.remove(hello, "o");
```

or `removeIgnoreCase`:

```
String hello = "hellO world";
String hellYeah = StringUtils.remove(hello, "o");
```