# How to check if some specific characters present in the string and remove those characters in java

Tags: java, string

I have a mobile number with some junk characters. I have to check whether the number contains 
the junk character `[#EEE]` in it, and if so, I should remove them:

```
String mobile = "999#EEE99999999";
String junktobechecked ="#EEE";
```

My output should be `99999999999`.

Note: This junk character is not a constant value.I have to get it from db table and check.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove a substring from a given String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775364/how-can-i-remove-a-substring-from-a-given-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char))

```
if(mobile.contains(junktobechecked))
{
    mobile = mobile.replace(junktobechecked, "");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`String.replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) - note that you don't really need to check if the string contains the junk string - `replace` would just do nothing in this case:

```
String mobile = "999#EEE99999999";
String junktobechecked ="#EEE";
mobile = mobile.replace(junktobechecked, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

[remove certain unwanted character](http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2014/01/remove-character-string-java-example-specific-certain-unwanted-characters.html). It might give you some idea on how to proceed.

```
String data = "12EEE34567890";   // imagine a large string loaded from a file
data.replace("EEE", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

first code is for find anything from string

```
your_string.contains("find_value")
```

now in case if you want to remove

```
 String arr [] = your_string.split("remove character"); 
String ans = "";
for(String t : arr)
        ans+=t;
```