# simplexml android Can't parse html with non-closing meta tag

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, simple-framework

I am trying to parse this xml string using simplexml in android:

```
"<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">
</head>
<body>
<doors>
<door id=\"1\" status=\"Closed\">
<door id=\"2\" status=\"Closed\">
<door id=\"3\" status=\"Closed\">
<door id=\"4\" status=\"Open\">
</door>
</door>
</door>
</door>
</doors>
</body>
</html>"
```

Yes, I know that the door tags should close immediately instead of after all the door tags have been declared, I have no control over this html!!!

I have a Doors class, and a Door class with attributes id and status. (The Doors class has a List)

Anyway, what seems to be breaking is the parsing of the  tag:

The Exception thrown is:

```
expected: /meta read: head (position:END_TAG </head>@1:87 in java.io.StringReader@41ddc090)
```

I can see that it was expecting a closing meta tag, which doesn't exist. This tag is useless to me, how can I skip it? I just care about the door ids/statuses.

Thanks

Also, in case you care about the classes:

Doors.java

```
@Root(name="doors", strict=false)
public class Doors {
@ElementList(name="door")
private List<Door> doorList;

public Doors(){};

public List<Door> getDoors(){
    return doorList;
}

public int getNumDoors(){
    return doorList==null ? 0 : doorList.size();
}
}
```

Door.java

```
@Root(name="door")
public class Door {
@Attribute
private String id;
@Attribute
private String status;

public String getID(){
    return id;
}
public String getStatus(){
    return status;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove the meta tag or even the head tag from the document  before passing it to the parser.
If it is stored in a string use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775364/how-can-i-remove-a-substring-from-a-given-string)

Comment: Thanks, I'll just have to do this. I was hoping to be able to iterate over the tag completely, but since it's hardcoded and not subject to change, String.replace will do fine.