# Get File Name of mediafire link android

Tags: android, get, mediafire

I´m trying to get the Name of the file from a mediafirelink but I don´t know how:C

I tested it with postman and i get many Information but in one line was it:

```html
                                            <div class="fileName">Name v.1.2.2b.apk</div>
                                            <div class="fileType">
                                                <span>Archive</span>
                                                <span> (.APK)
                                                    <span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <ul class="dlInfo-Details">
                                                    <li>File size: 
                                                        <span>13.37 MB</span>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>Uploaded: 
                                                        <span>2017-03-19 16:59:52</span>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>Uploaded From: 
                                                        <span></span>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
```

How can i get this specific line from a get response of Postman and how can i make it it android ?

Sry for my english I´m from Germany ;|

Thanks for your help

MFG Cem

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex to get the line `<div class="fileName">Name v.1.2.2b.apk</div>` quite easily (hint, http://regexr.com/ is pretty useful for this).

Then you just need to remove the opening and the closing div tags, which is relatively easy too, for example you could [remove a substring from a given string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775364/how-can-i-remove-a-substring-from-a-given-string).

Comment: And how can i do this in android ?

Comment: Your questions are way too broad and show that you haven't really searched at all for instructions on the internet -- nevertheless, you need to look up how to use regex on android, I already linked you how to do the second part.