# Can we Check directly in java that a set of substring is present in larger string

Tags: java

Ex.
.com is present in amazon.com
for that contains work in reverse order 
it check "amazon.com".contains(".com) 
but I need to find that
.com is contained in amazon.com or not
as I have a list of such(.com,.org , etc.) values to check

Comment: `String#endsWith`?

Comment: why is that contains() check not your answer?

Comment: `"amazon.com".contains(".com)` does exactly what you want

Comment: i want the reverse of it

Comment: string.endswith() can check for a specific value ... i have a hashset of values such as .com, .org, .in and so on ... and i need to find the strings that contains these values

Comment: i don't get your necessity for the reverse operation since you have a list of string to check.
What's stopping you from using a simple contains over all those items?

Comment: You are asking whether we can get the original string using a substring?

Comment: If you want some extreme efficiency, then you should write the loop yourself, map the values you want to check and compare their characters to the ones in the string.

Comment: to check for every string i need to go through the list of (.com,.org,etc) again and again, but i need a more efficient algo to do so

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know if a given string is substring from another string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804652/how-to-know-if-a-given-string-is-substring-from-another-string-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
private boolean checkUrl(String url, List<String> suffixes) {
    boolean isValid = false;
    //Loop through all the correct suffixes
    for(String suffix : suffixes) {
        //If the suffix exists then we can set the variable to true and break the loop so we can return true.
        if(url.endsWith(suffix)) {
            isValid = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: this is very slow of u need to check for 1M values

Answer (score 0):

Use **regex**

it will true when last string match.

```
    String str = "amazon.com";
    System.out.println(str.matches(".*(com|org|in)"));
```

Comment: what if the values get increase

Comment: Values will not matter, it will always check last ending string which are in brace (com|org|in).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to split your search algorithm into something like this:

```
convert
[".com", ".org"]
to
[
    '.': [
        'c': [
            'o': [
                'm': []
            ]
        ],
        'o': [
            'r': [
                'g': []
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Then you can loop over all characters in your input string and find the char tree of that individual char.
Then you can walk to the end of the tree and when you find an empty map at some point, you have found a match. If you do not find a map at all, then it is not a match.

This class will compile the search tree and have a method to match with some input

```
public class CharSearch
{
    private final Map<Character, CharSet> charSets;

    public CharSearch(String[] values)
    {
        charSets = new HashMap<>();
        for (String value : values)
            addValue(value);
    }

    public void addValue(String value)
    {
        addValue(value.toCharArray(), 0);
    }

    public void addValue(char[] value, int index)
    {
        if (value == null || value.length == 0)
            return;

        CharSet charSet = charSets.computeIfAbsent(value[index], k -> new CharSet());
        charSet.addValue(value, index +1);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return getClass().getName() + charSets.toString();
    }

    public int match(String input)
    {
        char[] characters = input.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++)
        {
            CharSet charSet = charSets.get(characters[i]);
            if (charSet != null)
            {
                if (charSet.match(characters, i) >= 0)
                    return i;
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}

class CharSet
{
    final Map<Character, CharSet> nextChars;
    boolean isLocked = false;

    CharSet()
    {
        this.nextChars = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return nextChars.toString();
    }

    void addValue(char[] value, int index)
    {
        if (isLocked)
            return;
        if (value.length <= index)
        {
            isLocked = true;
            nextChars.clear();
            return;
        }

        CharSet charSet = nextChars.computeIfAbsent(value[index], k -> new CharSet());
        charSet.addValue(value, index +1);
    }

    int match(char[] input, int index)
    {
        if (nextChars.isEmpty())
            return index;

        index++;
        if (input.length <= index)
            return -1;

        CharSet charSet = nextChars.get(input[index]);
        if (charSet != null)
        {
            return (charSet.match(input, index));
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

This assumes that if you compile "or" and "org", org will simply be ignored.
If you compile ".blablabla1" and ".blablabla2", ".blablabla" will only be checked once.
For the reason of why the hell not, the match method returns the index of the first match that is found.

```
String[] values = {".com", ".org",};
CharSearch charSearch = new CharSearch(values);
System.out.println(charSearch.match("amazon.com"));
System.out.println(charSearch.match("amazon.cooo"));
```

This will print out "6" and "-1".

I assume that with very few values to check for (2 in this case), this will be slower than actually doing something simple like this:

```
public static boolean hasAny(String text, String[] values)
{
    for (String value : values)
    {
        if (text.contains(value))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But the more values you check for, the more efficient the SearchChar approach becomes and the less efficient the hasAny() approach becomes.
(Note that becoming more efficient doesnt mean that the runtime will go down.)

You can optimize this algorithm by mapping sets with only one child together:

```
[
    '.': [
        'com': [],
        'org': []
    ]
]
```

or by adding a length check for the minimal length of each tree compared to the remaining length of the string (char[]) you are evaluating

or by skipping multiple characters with some high intelligence prediction...

But this should be enough to play with ;)

EDIT:
The efficiency here comes in when all your inputs (for example) start with a dot.
In the simple check, it will take O(n * t) where n is the number of characters in your input and t is the number of values you check to find starting characters of matches.

In the CharSearch, it will take O(n) to find starting characters of matches.
With a final complexity of O(n * (1~L)) where L is the highest length of the values you put in... which is the same complexity as String.contains() if I am not mistaken.

(That big O notation may not be the right notation though, but I think it should be pretty clear for people who understand it.)